# Not able to create New Titanium Mobile Module Project in Titanium 1.8.0.1

Tags: android, titanium-modules

I'm not at all able to create a mobile module in my new Titanium Studio. It shows me error as `Target platform(s) not selected (Missing required Android Add-Ons[addon.+google.+apis.+7, addon.+google.+apis.+8])`.

I have [attaching](http://screencast.com/t/zxzgwyTPOt) the image of error I got. I also updated everything in my Android SDK, and [this](http://screencast.com/t/llbgXa3NHH) is my Android SDK summary.

===========

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to open your android manager and download google api 7 and 8 specifically.